# Docker Nginx weird behaviors

Tags: laravel, docker, nginx

I am writing an nginx container to host a laravel site. Currently I am working on the nginx container and experiencing a weird behavior. Ever other other request you get can not connect and the other times you get the welcome page.

Here is my multi stage build

```
#
# PHP Dependencies
#
FROM composer:1.7 as vendor

COPY database/ database/

COPY composer.json composer.json
COPY composer.lock composer.lock

RUN composer install \
    --ignore-platform-reqs \
    --no-interaction \
    --no-plugins \
    --no-scripts \
    --prefer-dist

#
# Frontend
#
FROM node:8.11 as frontend

RUN mkdir -p /app/public

COPY package.json webpack.mix.js /app/
COPY resources/ /app/resources/

WORKDIR /app

RUN npm install && npm run production

#
# Application
#
FROM nginx:latest

# Set upstream conf and remove the default conf
# RUN echo "upstream php-upstream { server php:9000; }" > /etc/nginx/conf.d/upstream.conf \
#     && rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/

COPY . /var/www/studyup

COPY --from=vendor /app/vendor/ /var/www/vendor/
COPY --from=frontend /app/public/js/ /var/www/public/js/
COPY --from=frontend /app/public/css/ /var/www/public/css/
COPY --from=frontend /app/mix-manifest.json /var/www/mix-manifest.json

EXPOSE 80 443
```

THe nginx config file

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
daemon off;

events {
  worker_connections  2048;
  multi_accept on;
  use epoll;
}

http {
  server_tokens off;
  sendfile on;
  tcp_nopush on;
  tcp_nodelay on;
  keepalive_timeout 15;
  types_hash_max_size 2048;
  client_max_body_size 20M;
  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type application/octet-stream;
  access_log /dev/stdout;
  error_log /dev/stderr;
  gzip on;
  gzip_disable "msie6";

  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!DSS';

  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
  include /etc/nginx/sites-available/*.conf;
  open_file_cache off; # Disabled for issue 619
  charset UTF-8;
}
```

The sites available config

```
server {

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    # For https
    # listen 443 ssl;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on;
    # ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/default.crt;
    # ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/default.key;

    server_name testsite.com;
    root /var/www/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        fastcgi_pass php;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        #fixes timeouts
        fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/letsencrypt/;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/laravel_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/laravel_access.log;
}
```

I am not sure what is going on> I tried using the nginx latest and I could not even get the welcome page to go away. I personally have not been able to find anything about what is going on, but I might now what to search also. Any help would be great